# Entity Framework 4.1 Poco Classes Avoid multiple db roundtrips

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using EF 4.1 with Poco Classes.

When I get multiple entities like:

```
var users = db.Users.Where(u=>u.IsActive).ToList();
var transactions = db.Transactions.Where(t=>t.IsActive).ToList();
var customers = db.Customers.Where(c=>c.IsActive).ToList();
```

In this scenario the database is being hit 3 times? And if so is there any way to force EF 4.1 to make those calls in just 1 round-trip?

I'm asking this because I have a function that will have to get like 14 Entities and Update other 17. So would be great to know how is that working behind the scenes.

Comment: What are the relationship's between the three entities? You can check by looking at the navigation properties created for each one.

Comment: There is no relation between them. Are separate catalogs. I was reading that EF 5 will support multiple entities by calling stored procedures, so that will be great because you can create 1 SP that get 5 tables and EF 5 will map every table with a model. But right now I think its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since there is no relation and there are multiple tables involved there must be multiple trips made when using EF 4.1. This is because there is no way to provide some sort of JOIN between these tables to merge the multiple SQL statements. Although multiple trips must be made, doing each trip under one connection by switching between the DbSets while retaining the same context (if possible) will still be relatively painless.